# Terraform map from files in a directory

Tags: loops, terraform

guys!

My goal is to gather (merge) configs from YAML files into single Terraform map. E.g. I have the following 2 YAMLs:

- `config/file1.yml`

  ```yaml
  section1:
     property11: value11
     property12: value12
  ```
- `config/file2.yml`

  ```yaml
  section2:
     property21: value21
     property22: value22
  ```

What I need is the resulting config as follows (expressed as YAML below for readability, but of course it should be terraform map):

```yaml
 section1:
   property11: value11
   property12: value12

 section2:
   property21: value21
   property22: value22
```

What I came up with at the moment is the following:

```
locals {
  config = { for yaml_file in fileset("${path.module}/config/", "*.yml"):
    yaml_file => file("${path.module}/config/${yaml_file}"
  }
}
```

But I am not sure with how to proceed further. Could you, please, point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`merge`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/merge#merge-function) function to combine the yaml maps into a single terraform map.

```
locals {
  base_path     = "${path.module}/config"
  files         = fileset(local.base_path, "*.yml")
  file_content  = [for f in local.files : yamldecode(file("${local.base_path}/${f}"))]
  terraform_map = merge(local.file_content...)
  yaml_output   = yamlencode(local.terraform_map)
}

output "result" {
  value = local.file_content
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Conor! `merge(var...)` was the missing part!